# Integration Jira - GitLab

Tags: jira, gitlab

I would like to exploit the integration between the two tools to be able to automatically create a branch in GitLab for every new Bug or Feature ticket created in Jira.

I would like to know if (i) it is possible; (ii) what is the link between the two tools (I guess the unique ID number assigned by Jira); (iii) assuming the first point is true, what happens to the created branch when I close the Jira issue (e.g. I've mistakenly created a bug fix that was not needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Jira in conjunction with GitHub so I'll try my best to help you.

I) This is definitely possible.

II) We used to use the unique ID given to a ticket and include it within in the branch name this creates a link between both tools. Any changes committed on the branch will be shown in JIRA.

III) From experience when this happens the branch will persist and will need to be deleted manually using a console we used to use a .git console and used a delete command.

I also found through a quick google search some documentation on GitLab on integration with JIRA as well as some insight on creating branches.

Doc - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/jira.html

Branch - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/3886

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot pendants!

Comment: What happens if you change the label after the ticket ID? Does  the sync between the two tools still work?

Comment: @user3727540 The ticket ID binds the branch to the ticket so it is safe to change the label however I'm not certain the label will be changed for the branch and vice-versa

Comment: Hello ! I do not understand how the connection is made between the two. for JIRA for example, to make this configuration, should you install an addon?